# Zsh/Users/*******/.zshrc:13: unmatched

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I'm getting this message whenever I open the terminal ./Users/adebolaadesina/.zshrc:13: unmatched " . When I open the ~/.zshrc file, line 13 is blank. The ~/.zprofile and ~/.zshenv files are all empty when open with a text editor. What shld  I do? I don't want to reset the terminal or delete zsh to re-install.

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1;
 eval “%(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Comment: There is an `then` missing. And why do you have the `if` block three times in the `.zshrc` file? And for some reason you use `“` instead of `"`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to zsh and I must have duplicated the path. It's all good now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can remove 2 of the 3 identical `if` statements.

Comment: @chepner Yes,  I did and it work fine now. Thanks